# PHP5 email is not receiving when I use canonical email address?

Tags: php, email

Hi I have to send emails when a client is register on my web site. When ever I register using a gmail I got registration successfull email from my site. But when I use a canonical email like learner@learner.com or nibo@cukabula.com I dont get any mails. I checked my spam folder there also it is not comming. why this happening. I am using php5 email function for sending mails.

This is my email header

```
$headers2  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers2 .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers2 .= 'From: Client Order <info@nibogrp.com>';
```

Function I used

```
mail($Email,$order_subject2,$messageBody,$headers2);
```

Please help me.

Comment: If it works for one address and not others, then the problem lies in the mail transport - not in PHP. Why do you think gmail addresses are not canonical?

Comment: Hello symcbean why mails are not delivering to some domain's email address?. It always return failure message. But if we send mail from gmail it will deliver. Can you please suggest me a solution for that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a question falling a bit outside the PHP scope. Email acceptation rules are highly provider dependent, but here are a few common hints:

- use an email address in the From clause: `From: <email@domain.com>`
- set an envelope sender address using the `-f` parameter in [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)'s `additional_parameters`
- ensure you set up a [SPF record](http://www.openspf.org/) for the domain of your sender email
- check if your server's IP address is listed in any [DNSBL](http://www.dnsbl.info/), and follow the steps suggested for removal if it is listed in *any* of them.

Comment: Hi it is still not working. may I know any setting changes I have to made on cpanel?

Comment: @learner: the two first points are to change in your PHP code; the third one is at your registrar, and the last one on third-party websites. I think there is not much to do in cPanel.